# How to instantiate only one object in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, instantiation

```
int winer;

void Start() {
    winer = PlayerPrefs.SetInt("win", 0);
}

void Update() {
    winer = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("win");
    if(spawnPoint1.transform.position.x <= 10) {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("win", 1);
        chunks.enabled = false;
        if(winer == 1) {
            Instantiate(win, winPoint.transform.position, transform.rotation);
        }
    } else {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("win", 0);
    }
}
```

**How can I instantiate only one object for 2d sprite?**

*Thanks for your response*

Comment: `How to instantiate only one object in unity` -> By calling `Instantiate` only **once**? ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep track of the status in a variable so that the instantiation occurs only once.

```
bool instantiated; //is false by default
int winer;

void Start() {
    winer = PlayerPrefs.SetInt("win", 0);
}

void Update() {
    winer = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("win");
    if(spawnPoint1.transform.position.x <= 10) {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("win", 1);
        chunks.enabled = false;
        if(winer == 1 && !intstantiated) {
            Instantiate(win, winPoint.transform.position, transform.rotation);
            intstantiated = true;
        }
    } else {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("win", 0);
    }
}
```